# Android Studio 3.1: Compiled App keeps crashing after reopening with AudioFlinger errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm using Android Studio 3.1 to compile my app. It works fine on first load, but if I close the app (from the app drawer) and then re-open it, it crashes as soon as it launches, and can't ever be relaunched.

Note that this is a React Native project, and **I'm not using any audio capabilities of Android in my app**:

Android studio gives me these errorsin logcat.

```
e/AudioFlinger: Not enough memory for Audiotrack

04-16 09:58:15.508 1561-5451/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
04-16 09:58:15.508 1561-5451/? D/MemoryDealer:   AudioTrack (0xe837e2e0, size=4194304)
        0: 0xe837e2f0 | 0x00000000 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        1: 0xe837e350 | 0x000200E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        2: 0xe837e4e0 | 0x000401C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        3: 0xe87991e0 | 0x000602A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        4: 0xe8799410 | 0x00080380 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        5: 0xe837e670 | 0x000A0460 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        6: 0xe837e840 | 0x000C0540 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        7: 0xe8799720 | 0x000E0620 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        8: 0xe87998f0 | 0x00100700 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        9: 0xe8799a80 | 0x001207E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       10: 0xe8799c00 | 0x001408C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       11: 0xe837eaf0 | 0x001609A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       12: 0xe87992d0 | 0x00180A80 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       13: 0xe837ec80 | 0x001A0B60 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       14: 0xe837ee70 | 0x001C0C40 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       15: 0xe8799e60 | 0x001E0D20 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       16: 0xe71ee180 | 0x00200E00 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       17: 0xe71ee360 | 0x00220EE0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       18: 0xe71ee4f0 | 0x00240FC0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       19: 0xe8799f00 | 0x002610A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 

04-16 09:58:15.508 1561-5451/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
04-16 09:58:15.508 2536-7471/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
04-16 09:58:15.511 2536-7471/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
04-16 09:58:15.511 2536-7471/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
04-16 09:58:15.511 2536-7471/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@4f4786e
04-16 09:58:15.518 2536-7471/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@4f4786e
04-16 09:58:15.518 2536-5294/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
04-16 09:58:15.519 2536-5294/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
04-16 09:58:15.519 2536-5294/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ag.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ag.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:6) 
04-16 09:58:15.520 2536-5294/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @MatthiasHoste what code would be useful to see here? As I said I'm not using audio at all in my app so I can't pinpoint where this error is coming from at all...

Comment: I have the same issue, not using any recording feature either...